Google OAUth consent screen not showing sensitive or restricted scopes in local development
I'm in local development, testing Google's OAUth. I am able to authenticate, but for some reason, Google doesn't present me with the screen to agree to the sensitive and restricted scopes (e.g. https://mail.google.com/). I did add these scopes in the Google Console hours ago - why are they not showing up?
All I'm getting is this screen:

My app is in "Testing" mode, not verified.
I've read through the many issues on Stackoverflow regarding the OAuth screen but no luck.
I don't think it matters, but I'm using Supabase to initiate the OAuth flow. My understanding is that the scopes are fully managed on Google's end, and so I haven't been suspicious of Supabase or my code as the root cause:
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
  provider: "google",
  options: {
    redirectTo: "http://localhost:3000/callback", //after the google redirect, we need to redirect to this route
    queryParams: {
      access_type: "offline",
      prompt: "consent",
    },
  },


Turns out you have to actually request the scope. The Google console setting just allows you to request it.
      provider: "google",
      options: {
        redirectTo: "http://localhost:3000/callback", //after the google redirect, we need to redirect to this route
        queryParams: {
          access_type: "offline",
          prompt: "consent",
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly", //add scopes here
        },
      },
    });


yeah. looks like the ones you setup in gcp console is for verification purposes. once you apply for app verification, the scopes that were requested by your app should match with the ones you setup in gcp console. that's how i understand it.
